# Compatible lens for a Nikon 1 J1 camera

Tags: lens, nikon

I am looking for a 70-300mm lens for a Nikon 1 J1 camera.  I would appreciate any recommendations!

Comment: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Camera-Lenses/1-NIKKOR-Lenses/index.page?CID=SEM-Q114-Google_Nikon_-_DSA

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you want the equivalent focal length as a 70-300mm lens on a DSLR body?  If so, the J1 has a crop factor of 2.7x and that means you want something like the [Nikkor 30-110mm](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/acil/lenses/1_nikkor_vr_30-110mm_f38-56/index.htm) lens, which they make for the Nikon 1 series.

If you mean an actual 70-300mm lens, they also make a Nikon 1 series [70-300mm](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/acil/lenses/1_nikkor_vr_70-300mm_f45-56/index.htm)

Or you can buy the [FT1 Adapter](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/acil/lenses/mount_adapter_ft1/), which will let you mount any Nikon F mount lens on a Nikon 1 body, including any 3rd party lenses (Sigma, Tamron etc).

Which specific lens depends on your budget.